# C# How to pass a struct as a parameter to a method of a .DLL called by reflection?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I have a DLL that I call dynamically through reflection,
when I try to send a structure as a parameter, it generates the following error:
**"System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'MRaport' cannot be converted to type 'MRaport'."
How can I fix this?**

```
public struct MRaport
    {
        public int rapId;
        public string rapName;
        public string Level;
    }

private void CreateRap()
   {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"path\RapLibrary.dll");
       Type myLibraryType = assembly.GetType("XReport");
       object myLibraryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myLibraryType);

       bool x = true;
       MRaport mr = new MRaport { rapId = 1, rapName = "MxFolder", Level = "Red" };
       MethodInfo methodInfo = myLibraryType.GetMethod("fillRaport");
       object[] parameters = new object[] { x, mr };

       try
       {
          string result = (string)methodInfo.Invoke(myLibraryInstance, parameters);
          MessageBox.Show(result);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

Class Library (DLL):

```
public struct MRaport
    {
        public int rapId;
        public string rapName;
        public string Level;
    }

    public class XReport
    {
        public string fillRaport(bool x, MRaport mr)
        {
            if (x)
            {
               return mr.rapName;
            }
            else
            {
               return mr.Level;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `MRaport` isn't the `MRaport` in your class library, and so not the one that it's expecting. It doesn't matter that it *looks* kind of similar to the naked eye, it's still different.

So, what you need to do is first create the type from the class library (for example, with `Activator.CreateInstance`), fill in its fields (either by reflected types or by using `dynamic`) then pass it into the function call as you are now.

Comment: Generally speaking, the way this kind of stuff is generally done is by having a 3rd assembly both you and your class library are referencing, and that contains all the common interfaces between you two (so the structure in its entirety, and an interface `IReport` that you derive `XReport` from, and that contains that function definition). That way there is no reflection involved, only polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks Blindy! Your answer helped me understand what's wrong with my approach and implement the correct code.